# is searching a python list for an empty list inaccurate?

Tags: python, list

Why can b list be found in some_list even though it's not in some_list?

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> a is b
False
>>> some_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, a]
>>> some_list.index(b)
4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python's `list.index` searches tests for equality, not identity. `a` and `b` are not identical, but equal:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> a == b
True
```

Define [`__eq__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) on your objects a,b if you want a different definition of equality, for example:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
  return self is other
def __hash__(self):
  return 0 # Insert a more sensible, object-specific hash function here
```

Answer (score 7):

`.index` returns 4th position because it compares a and b, two empty lists. They are equal. If you do `a is b`, it compares the memory addresses of objects, and they are different, that's why this expression evaluates to False.

```
In [1]: a = []
In [2]: b = []
In [3]: a == b
Out[3]: True
```

Comment: Additional: Lists are mutable, so each assignment of [] to a variable results in a different object in memory. a=[]; b=[]; a is b # returns False. An example of the converse are Strings which are immutable.  Assigning the same string value to different variables essentially point to the same object in memory. a="Hello"; b="Hello"; a is b # returns True.

Comment: @tom: That's an implementation detail for small strings, but `a = "Hello" * 1000; b = "Hello" * 1000; (a is b) == False`.

Comment: Thanks eryksun, I didn't know that! So: a="Hello"+"World"; b="Hello"+"World"; (a is b) == False.

Comment: @tom it may or may not be, depending on the implementation. There is no reason to expect either outcome specifically, and no reason to write code that expects either outcome.

Answer (score 1):

They are different:

```
a is b
```

is true only if they are both bound to the same object.  However, index only checks if the values are equal.

To put a C example, `3 == 3` but

```
int a = 3;
int b = 3;
&a == &b // this is false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute the `a == b`. The '==' operator checks, if the values of variables are the same, and so does the index function. The `is` function comapres the variables id().

This might be helpful:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> id(a)
4299650400
>>> id(b)
4299730096
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
False
```

Also note this one:

```
>>> some_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, a]
>>> some_list.index(b)
4
>>> some_list[4] == b
True
>>> some_list[4] is b
False
```